# Delete data from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have add data on firestore Firebase but I don't have specific document because I use addSnapShotListener to retrieve the data. How can I delete the document when I don't know the name of it. Here is the code where I add the data:

```
mondayCollectionReference.document().set(userMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(TimeForm.this, "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) returns a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object.  That object gives you everything you need to know to delete it, especially its own [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#delete()) method.  It also has a [`getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getId()) method to help you remember its id.

So, you should store the DocumentReference object first before calling methods on it:

```
DocumentReference ref = mondayCollectionReference.document()
String id = ref.getId();
ref.set(...);
// use ref or id later if you want to delete it
```

Comment: So I can delete hole documents even if I use the addSnapshotListener and thus not knowing the id?

Comment: You can call delete() on a DocumentReference whenever you want without knowing its id.  The id is held within the reference itself.

Comment: @ Doug In my collection I have multiple documents how can I delete a specific document?