# Can't get the correct document id in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my `TimeForm` activity I add some data to Firestore but I don't add them in specific documents because I need to read them all using `.addSnapshotListener`
But I need to delete some of the documents. For example here are my documents in the Monday collection:

[image]

But when I tried to delete them doing this:

```
db.collection("monday").document()
    .delete()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work because I haven't set the document name. Then I asked how to get a documents id(here is the page: [Delete data from firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301470/delete-data-from-firestore/52301676#52301676)) it didn't send the correct document id. I added a test button and when I clicked it, it displayed a toast with the document's id but everytime I pressed it, it displayed random ids and none of them were correct. How can I delete those documents one by one of all of them at once.

Comment: In order to delete a document you have to pass its document id and then call delete() method. If you want to delete all the documents in a collection then first retrieve them and iterate a for loop to by getting uid of each document and then call delete() method.

Comment: I did String documentId = db.collection("Monday").document().getId(); And then I deleted it but it didn't pass the correct id and I added a button that everytime it was pressed it displayed a Toast with the documentId string and it displayed a wrong id each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it displayed random ids and none of them were correct.

This is happening because you aren't passing anything to the `document()` method. According to the official documentation of CollectionReference's [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) method:

> Returns a DocumentReference pointing to a new document with an auto-generated ID within this collection.

So everytime you call `document()` method without passing any argument, you get a **new** `auto-generated ID` which will never match with one of your existing one.

In order to delete a particular document, you need to pass the particular id of the document that you want to delete to the `document()` method. It might look something like this:

```
db.collection("monday").document("2wZg ... GmfS").delete().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Is there any possible way I could get the document name without setting it?

Comment: Yes you can, by calling `document.getId()` as specified in the official documentation regarding [Get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), right?

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: I will try it today and ill tell you if I have any problems, thanks for your help though =)

Comment: Sorry for being extremely late, but I had school ;-; Good new though, it worked!!          Thanks